# How to make sure that password is changed for a user in every 7 days in perl script

Tags: perl

I am new to perl , What I want to do is make sure that every user keeps modifying his password at least once 7 days . In case he has not, the system will either provoke him to change the password or log him out . But in my case say the file containing all the user Id and password are in a file `userid_passwd.txt` . So If a single user modifies or changes his password the filestamp for  the `userid_passwd.txt` will get changed . So even If one user follows the norm of modifying the password once in a week and rest avoids it they will be able to log in .

```
open WORDSLIST, $filename
    or die "can't open wordlist: $!";

if (-M WORDSLIST < 7.0) {  

    while ($name = <WORDSLIST>) {
        \\Do Something
    }
}
close WORDSLIST
    or die "couldn't close wordlist: $!";
```

But the code part `if (-M WORDSLIST < 7.0) {`  is not the thing I want as my file contains user id and password for each user in order which is latter assigned to a hash variable.

Comment: It's unclear whether you want to do this "for real" or if it's just a learning exercise, but, if you intend it to be a real password policy, then please... _don't do this_. Password change policies, especially one demanding such frequent changes, _increase_ the chance of successful attacks against the system because users will resort to easily-remembered passwords, usually something sequential (mypass1, mypass2, mypass3...), which makes them easier for attackers to guess.

Comment: Not to mention that anyone breaking into your system will come across this treasure trove of username/password combos stored in what I am assuming is plaintext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your file currently holds both `username` and `password`, you could also add a `last_changed` as a datetime and do your logic based on that.

Comment: yeah I guess in that way I could prevent making Individual file for Individual User . I guess I can try this :)

Comment: anyway, it looks like your app is evolving - maybe it is a good moment to switch to using databases.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to track *somewhere* when a user last changed their password.  Or alternatively, keep 7 copies of your password file, aged 1 through 7 days old, and see if a user's password is the same as it was.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion , I can always do that ..But I wanted to know if there is a way in Which I can do away with just 1 file COntaining information about all the users and their password .

Answer (score 2):

If you want to build a more flexible and grown-up solution, you can use a simple [SQLite](http://sqlite.org) database together with [ORLite](http://p3rl.org/ORLite) to store both passwords ([salted hashes!](http://perlgems.blogspot.de/2012/05/password-storage-with-salted-hashes.html)) and last modified time stamps like this (incomplete, just to get you started):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use FindBin '$Bin';
use Crypt::SaltedHash;
use ORLite {
    file    => "$Bin/login.db",
    create  => sub { shift->do('
        CREATE TABLE login (
            user            TEXT    NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
            salted_hash     TEXT    NOT NULL,
            last_modified   INTEGER NOT NULL
        )
    ')},
};

# ...

my $login = Login->load($name);
say 'password ok' if $crypter->validate($login->salted_hash, $password);
say 'password change ok' if time - $login->last_modified < 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
```